# JQuery Auto Complete AJAX Call URL parameter alternate

Tags: apex, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am implementing a jquery auto complete search box. Am having JSON file in static resource and referencing it in ajax URL parameter. It is working perfectly. But now I want to make the JSON values dynamic. Am able to create a dynamic JSOn data in apex controller class and storing it in string getter setter variable. Now how could I reference this string JSON data in URL parameter of AJAX call.

Previous way

```
 $.ajax({
        'async': true,
        'global': false,
        'url': "{!URLFOR($Resource.techareasubtecharea, '/techandsubtechareacombinations.json')}",
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
           .............
           .............
        }
})
```

Now I made dynamic JSON string data in apex constructor with getter setter variable. If I give this string JSON data to the URL parameter of AJAX, it not taking as it needs only URL.  Then how do I give this String JSON data as input to this?.
Any help is appreciable.